# "Using future continuous where future simple is perfectly fine "

Tags: tenses

I am aware of the general meaning of "future continuous ". But sometimes I see to use "future  continuous in a different way where "future simple is perfectly fine ". I am giving a couple of examples :

1) The Tigers have produced a number of impressive
performances in recent times, including a Test win on
home soil against England. With that in mind, Khawaja
says Australia will not be taking their next opponents
lightly.

What if I write '"With that in mind, Khawaja
says Australia will not take their next opponents
lightly "?  What will be the difference?

2) Australia have not played a Test in Bangladesh since
2006 when former fast bowler Jason Gillespie scored a
memorable double-century in what turned out to be his
final Test. And he had some advice for the Australian
team who will be visiting this time around, light-heartedly
asking them to watch the footage of his terrific innings.

What if I write " And he had some advice for the Australian
team who will  visit this time around.....?  what will  be the difference?  Please help me out, Native speakers.

Comment: ' ... will not be taking their next opponents lightly' strongly connotes that they will be continuing to get ready for this encounter; ' ... will not take their next opponents lightly' gives more room for the suspicion 'they might put half an hour more practice in the day before the match'. 'Take X seriously' is probably mobile between punctive and stative.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth What about the second one? Actually I was expecting a detailed explanation as an answer.

Comment: please use `**` around bold sections, **like this**, rather than breaking readability by using headings :)

Comment: The second example is probably even more subtle. 'who will be visiting' sounds slightly more idiomatic (though neither is ungrammatical), probably because 'be visiting' sounds better without an object than 'visit', and less abrupt. I'm not prepared to go to an 'answer' because I will almost certainly not be able to find references (eg articles) backing my views.